# Background Application in AppHarbor and Logentries

Tags: backgroundworker, appharbor, logentries

Now I've a web application and 3 background application in AppHarbor .
I want to use logentries to log each app in different location.
based on logentries docs for AppHarbor https://logentries.com/doc/appharbor/ the token keys are read from web.config and app.config [configuration vars] enforced by appharbor.

How can I configure each application to log in different log location (eg. Appharbor/Website, AppHarbor/Console1, AppHarbor/Console2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the config vars injected by AppHarbor by specifying the Token in the appender/target definition. Not sure which framework you're using but if its NLog then
where you have this line in your web/app.config

`<target name="logentries" type="Logentries" debug="true"
    layout="${date:format=ddd MMM dd} ${time:format=HH:mm:ss} ${date:format=zzz yyyy} ${logger} : ${LEVEL}, ${message}"/>`

Add token="abc" so that you have this:

`<target name="logentries" type="Logentries" debug="true" token="abc"
    layout="${date:format=ddd MMM dd} ${time:format=HH:mm:ss} ${date:format=zzz yyyy} ${logger} : ${LEVEL}, ${message}"/>`

And then if you're using the log4net plugin, where you have this section:

`<appender name="LeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.LogentriesAppender, LogentriesLog4net">
    <Debug value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy} %logger %: %level%, %m" />
    </layout>
  </appender>`

Add  so that you have this:

`<appender name="LeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.LogentriesAppender, LogentriesLog4net">
    <Debug value="true" />
    <Token value="abc" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy} %logger %: %level%, %m" />
    </layout>
  </appender>`

Token values set here will take precedence over those injected by Appharbor, so for each app that has its own web/app.config you can enter your own token using this method.

Comment: It worked fine, but can I make single application to log using multi token? for example : I have 5 locations in logentries each one has its own token , I want to log to those locations from single app  or webapp

Comment: I can look to extending the library to have this functionality, I guess it will require some logic though, do you have an example of the logic you'd use to determine which log events go where?

Answer (score 0):

I Found that I can set the token in runtime by below lines :

```
private static readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

appender = (LogentriesAppender)log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders()[0];
appender.Token = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

//now log method will use my token 
log.Info("Hello World");
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the library uses a queue that the log messages are pushed into while the background thread polls the queue and ships them off, but currently the token is prefixed to the messages after they're pulled from the queue, this could cause a race condition of sorts if you change the token thinking it will only affect messages you log after that point. Let me see if theres any drawback to prefixing the token before pushing to the queue